# Not Match Regex for Email

Tags: regex, mongodb, email

Not sure I'm doing this right.

```
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

db.test.find({ "Email" : { $regex : re}}).count()
```

This returns back the 500 document count I expect...but of the 1000 documents in the collection, there are intentionally 500 INVALID email addresses.  Yes, I can do the math, but I actually do eventually want to retrieve all the bad addresses.  How?

```
db.test.find({ "Email" : {$not:{ $regex : re}}})
```

gives me an error where I would have expected 500 documents in the resulting cursor

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$not cannot have a regex",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

of course, the documentation seems to support the idea that $regex is not support as part of $not.  The syntax of the "re" variable is already really complex.

What do I have to do in native mongo / javascript to query a collection of documents where their email element is NOT a valid email address based on a complex regular expression?

Fairly new to mongo...missing sql server badly...but willing and enthusiastic to offer a client this solution for so many of the great things it's going to offer this project.

Thanks for any insight you (all) might be able to provide.

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is off and according to the docs you can put a regex into a `$not` expression.

This is will return all email addresses that do no match your regex.

`db.test.find( { Email: { $not: re } } )`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/

Comment: Interestingly this does in fact work. So the inclusion of `$regex` as an explicit seems to be the problem.

Comment: Right...what I meant by $not and regular expressions was the $regex, not expressions in general.  And clearly this solution works just fine...though I swear I tried it...in fact, I thought I had tried it using the literal regex string and not the variable and it failed...but just tried again and it worked fine.  Thanks 88 for pointing out I'm clearly just an idiot...solution worked just fine.  I guess I have a lot to learn yet.  NOW, onto getting this to work in Java :)